# mySql database table sync between Local and Remote using VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I am trying to update multiple tables from local mysql database to remote mysql database. Following code I am using for insert/update the remote table.
But I am getting the following error.

> System.InvalidOperationException:  'Update unable to find
> TableMapping['productexceltemplatetransfer'] or DataTable
> 'productexceltemplatetransfer'.'

```
Dim tblStr As String = "select id,tablename from transtablename"
        Dim transtblDT As DataTable = RetDatatable(tblStr, <<Local Connection String>>)
        For i As Integer = 0 To transtblDT.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            strSql = "select * from " & transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString 
            Using mcon As New MySqlConnection(<<Local Connection String>>)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSql, mcon)
                mcon.Open()
                aDt = RetDatatable(strSql, <<Local Connection String>>)
                'da.Fill(ds)
                ds = New DataSet(transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString)
                ds.Tables.Add(aDt)
                mcon.Close()
            End Using

            Using mcon As New MySqlConnection(<<Remote Connection String>>)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString, mcon)
                Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
                mcon.Open()

                da.Update(ds, transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString)
                mcon.Close()
            End Using

        Next
```

Requesting your help how to resolve this issue.

Comment: When you debug, what exactly is the value of _transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename")_?  Are you sure that is actually returning the table name your expecting?  And does that table actually exist in the target DB?

Comment: Yes actual table name is fetching i.e. "productexceltemplatetransfer". This is exists in both the database with same structure.

Comment: Are you sure you've got the catalogue right in your connection string, because by my eye if the table exists, there isn't a problem.  Does the Select command of your da error, or the update command?

Comment: Yes all the connection string is ok. Error occurs in the line: da.Update(ds, transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString)

Comment: Requesting your help how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I have changes the code and it is working fine.

```
Dim tblStr As String = "select id,tablename from transtablename"
        Dim transtblDT As DataTable = RetDatatable(tblStr, <<Local Connection String>>)
        For i As Integer = 0 To transtblDT.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim ds As New DataSet
            strSql = "select * from " & transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString 
            Using mcon As New MySqlConnection(<<Local Connection String>>)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSql, mcon)
                mcon.Open()
                da.Fill(ds, transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString)
                mcon.Close()
            End Using

            Using mcon As New MySqlConnection(<<Remote Connection String>>)
                Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " & transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString, mcon)
                Dim cb As New MySqlCommandBuilder(da)
                mcon.Open()
For j As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
                ds.Tables(0).Rows(j).SetAdded()
            Next j
                da.Update(ds, transtblDT.Rows(i).Item("tablename").ToString)
                mcon.Close()
            End Using

        Next
```